# Trigger one component method after other component fully load

Tags: angular, lifecycle-hook

I have two components, both are loading in my `<app-root>` like this:

```
<app-header [calendarReference]="calendarRef"></app-header>

<app-calendar #calendarRef></app-calendar>
```

and `index.html`

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Is there a way to trigger `<app-header>` component method after `<app-calendar>` component is fully load?

Comment: do you want to call a public method defined in `<app-header>` once `<app-calender>` has loaded/rendered?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Output` decorator. I don't know about your code, so I will assume the components:

**In your CalendarComponent:**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class CalendarComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @Output() calendarLoaded: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        console.log('Calendar Loaded');
        this.calendarLoaded.emit(true);
    }
}
```

**Catch the event in you app.component.html:**

```
<app-header #appHeader></app-header>

<app-calendar #calendarRef (calendarLoaded)="afterCalendarLoaded()"></app-calendar>
```

**.. and this is how your app.component.ts would look:**

```
import {Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header.component';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('appHeader') appHeader: HeaderComponent;

    afterCalendarLoaded(){
        this.appHeader.someMethod();
    }    
}
```

Here is a working [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/3McNV0wqjFxoK10NYxhx?p=preview). See the console log.

Comment: Your answer works and it solved my problem but causes another - header.components method - in your plunker it's someMethod() - triggers like 10 times, no clue why, in this method i'm loading preety big object, maybe this causes it?

Comment: depends on how many times your `<app-header>` get initialize.

Comment: it gets initialized only once in `app.component` and i have only `constructor()` method in `app-header`. I dont have any lifecycle hooks in it

Comment: how many times do you see the "Calendar Loaded" log in the console? `someMethod()` will get called everytime the calendar loads.

Comment: Ok, i think i need you to understand whole concept so you can help me :) `someMethod() { this.drivers = this.calendarReference.drivers; console.log(this.drivers); }`                                                    `this.driversService.getDrivers() .subscribe( (drivers) => { this.drivers=Object.keys(drivers).map(function (key) {                                     return drivers[key]; }); }); `                         `getDrivers()` method is called in calendar component `constructor()` and that's basically workflow of my app. The problem is that i see console.log(this.drivers) like 10 times

Comment: I'll have a look at it in a while :)

Comment: Thank you so much bro :)

Answer (score 3):

Create an **`Output()`** (custom event) on the `CalenderComponent` and fire that when the component is considered loaded (preferably in the `ngAfterViewInit` callback)

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class CalenderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Output() loaded = new EventEmitter();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loaded.emit();
  }
}
```

Then you can trigger any method on the `HeaderComponent` from the template when the `loaded` event is fired (ommited the other details in the template for brevity)

```
<app-header #header></app-header>
<app-calendar (loaded)="header.someMethodToCall()"></app-calendar>
```

Comment: you forgot `implements AfterViewInit` ;)

Comment: why not needed? how will you `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook invoke?

Comment: The interface is just for tooling, you just need the method for it to be invoked. Try it yourself :)

Comment: didnt know that, I'll try

Comment: @Faisal - https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#interfaces-are-optional-technically